# Div above footer is affecting the footer styling, how to fix this?

Tags: html, css, dom

I am trying to develop a Help me function for our users. For this purpose, I am trying to put a div right above my footer. But, my div styling is affecting the footer, and I am not able to figure out why.

The look I am trying to achieve -
[image: I want that Need help image right above the footer]

How it looks when I try to implement -

[image]

My styling affects the footer styling.

Here is my html code

```
<div class="help-img pull-right">
    <a href="https://google.com">
        <img src="~/Content/images/icon-help.png?version=@buildVersion" />
    </a>
</div>
<footer class="clearfix">
    <div class="pull-left">
        <span id="footerYear"></span> &copy; <a href="https://viacommediaservices.visualstudio.com" target="_blank">VMS Web @ViewContext.Controller.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version</a>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <a href="~/content/help/VMSWeb One Sheet.pdf" target="_blank">VMS Web User Guide</a> |
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick=";">Terms of Use</a>
    </div>
</footer>
```

My CSS -

```
.help-img {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 50px;
    margin-right: 28px;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Normally `.clearfix` classes work by adding a pseudo element _after_ their content to clear their content's floats. Since you don't have a `.clearfix` class wrapping the element you added before the footer, its float isn't cleared before starting the footer. Try wrapping that new element in a `.clearfix` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your elements to be able to position them relatively. Or you can use `flexbox` layout model, which is more suitable in this case.

```css
.wrapper{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.help-img {
    margin-right: 28px;
    align-self:flex-end;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
}

.clearfix{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  background-color:#f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="help-img pull-right">
      <a href="https://google.com">
      <img src="~/Content/images/icon-help.png?version=@buildVersion" />
      </a>
      Need Help? <strong>Click Here</strong>
  </div>
  <footer class="clearfix">
      <div class="pull-left">
          <span id="footerYear"></span> &copy; <a href="https://viacommediaservices.visualstudio.com" target="_blank">VMS Web @ViewContext</a>
      </div>
      <div class="pull-right">
          <a href="~/content/help/VMSWeb One Sheet.pdf" target="_blank">VMS Web User Guide</a> |
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick=";">Terms of Use</a>
      </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This helped :)